# Why do my Google Voice calls get forwarded to another phone when forwarding isn't set?

Tags: voip, google-voice

I have a Google Voice number ggg-ggg-gggg and a cell phone number ccc-ccc-cccc that I configured (in my phone's voice mail settings) to use Google Voice as voicemail.  Works great.  (Note that I besides voice mail, nothing else is set to call my Google Voice number ggg-ggg-gggg and no one calls me there.)

Now I want to start using my Google Voice number and have it ring my home number hhh-hhh-hhhh.  When people call my Google Voice number it rings my home phone and then goes into Google Voice voice mail as expected.  Works great here too.

Here's the problem - when people call my cell phone directly at ccc-ccc-cccc, it then rings my Google Voice number.  As I said before, my cell phone is set to use Google Voice, so why is it ringing my phone phone after my cell phone?

Comment: How did you set up voicemail? Is it an app on your phone or did you use your keypad to program in the forwarding code?

Comment: I just used the Google Voice programming code that I got from my Google Voice settings page.

Answer (score 1):

Google Voice voicemail works on your cell phone by setting up conditional call forwarding. All the settings you put in your phone made your cell phone carrier forward any calls you do not answer for any reason, (phone turned off, you hit ignore, or you just let it ring) to your Google Voice Number.

When this happens Google Voice treats that call like anyone else calling. It will ring all of the phones you have listed and checked under "forwards to:" on the phones tab in your Google Voice settings.

If those phones go unanswered it then sends them to voicemail.

The main problem I have with that is when someone calls your cell phone it rings say 4 times, then forwards the call to GV which rings your home phone 4 times, so your caller hears a lot of ringing, and at least in my case hang up before actually getting to my voicemail a lot of the time.

It is nice on one hand, if someone calls you on your cell when you are home you can just hit ignore on your cell, and it will automatically ring your home phone, and you can take the call there.

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things.  My issue is that when someone calls my cell phone's *actual* number, it is then ringing my Google Voice number.  In otherwords the opposite situation of norma.

Comment: @Emilio I have updated my answer to better explain the process.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup Google Voice Voicemail on your phone, you may have set ALL numbers to forward to your ggg-ggg-gggg instead of just voicemail calls.  This is most likely the case, and I can tell you how to fix it, but I need to know your cell phone carrier.

Comment: @Theo - it's Verizon? But no numbers are being forwarded at all. Calls to my phone don't get forwarded, they just go to gv voicemail. Unless I'm misunderstanding what you meant?

Comment: @Theo - Turns out each of us were partially right and partially wrong.  When I said that I have no call forwarding this was technically not the case because when you set your phone to use a different voice mail provider, that is a forwarder from the phone's point of view.  So I was partially wrong on this.  You were partially wrong because there's actually no difference between forwarding all cals to the ggg number instead of just voice mail calls.  It's the same thing, because if your voice mail to Google (or anyone else), ALL calls will end up there by default.